# How do I make use of the full SD-card after installing ev3dev

Tags: ev3dev

After writing the image to the 8G microSD-card, initial setup of network and installation of git (with apt-get) I could not install anything else since I was out of diskspace. This confused me. But `df -h` shows me that `/dev/mmcblk0` has a size of just under 1G. `/dev/mmcblk0p1` has a size of 40M.

So I got a card with roughly 7G unused and unaccessible. How do I get hold of it?

When I insert the card in my laptop (Ubuntu) it does no longer automount itself and when I try to get some info about it I get this with `parted` and `lsblk`:

```
$ sudo parted -l /dev/mmcblk0p1
Model: ATA HTS721080G9SA00 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  76.8GB  76.8GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      76.8GB  80.0GB  3219MB  extended
 5      76.8GB  80.0GB  3219MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Error: /dev/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label                              

$ sudo lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  74.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0  71.5G  0 part /
├─sda2        8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5        8:5    0     3G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   7.4G  0 part
```

What can I do:

- Could I resize the disk in the current installation?
- Could I do a new installation an during the installation procedure set the size of the final result?
- Could I create new partitions in the unpartitioned area and move the OS to that partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install ev3dev with an image file dated 1 May, 2015 or later, it should automatically expand the root partition to fill the space available on the SD card. Older releases are no longer supported.

If it does not do this, you should report a bug a https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues. Be sure to read http://www.ev3dev.org/support/#github-issues first.

Comment: May 10? So in 2 days?

Comment: Oops. that was supposed to be 1 May. I've corrected it.